# While loop not printing all answers

Tags: php, mysql

This might be really simple, but i cannot figure out the problem with this code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from Temporary_Stock_Transfer where Emp_ID = '$emp_id' and Company_ID = '$company_id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='3'><i>You currenty have no items</i></td></tr>";
    }else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo mysql_num_rows($sql);
            echo 'reached';
            $book_id = $row[1];
            $sql = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select title from Book where Book_ID = '$book_id'"));
            echo "<tr><td>".$sql[0]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td><span class='label label-important'>Remove</span></td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

Now based on my database the query is returning 2 results, the `echo mysql_num_rows($sql)` also gives out `2`. However the reached is echoed only once. Does anyone see a potential problem with the code?

**P.S: My bad, `$sql` is being repeated, that was a silly mistake**

Comment: My guess is your query inside the loop is failing. You should check that your queries are correct by checking mysql_error()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it'll be because you are ressetting the sql variable

```
            $sql = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select title from Book where Book_ID = '$book_id'"));
```

when you are still using it in the while loop. :P

Answer (score 4):

It will only `echo` once because of this line :

```
$sql = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select title from Book where Book_ID = '$book_id'"));
```

your overwriting the `$sql` variable.

Why not just run a single query and join the data you require ?

Comment: Thanks, i will fix that but could you please tell why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

try (`$sql2` instead of `$sql` and `$sql[0]` to `$sql2[0]`):

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from Temporary_Stock_Transfer where Emp_ID = '$emp_id' and Company_ID = '$company_id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='3'><i>You currenty have no items</i></td></tr>";
    }else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo mysql_num_rows($sql);
            echo 'reached';
            $book_id = $row[1];
            $sql2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select title from Book where Book_ID = '$book_id'"));
            echo "<tr><td>".$sql2[0]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td><span class='label label-important'>Remove</span></td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think on the last line $sql[0] should be $sql2[0]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably this line:

```
 $sql = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select title from Book where Book_ID = '$book_id'"));
```

Try using a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the $sql variable inside the loop, therefore the next time you run $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql), the value will be different (probably won't be any based on your code).

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while loop you are re-using the same variable: `$sql`. This is used to control the terminating condition of the loop.

Using a different variable name, e.g. `$sql2` should leave the original variable intact and the loop should proceed as expected.